# Play video downloaded through CloudKit as CKAsset - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, avplayer, cloudkit

I'm making an app that records video, uploads it to iCloud using CloudKit with a CKAsset, then downloads the file and plays it in an AVPlayer. This is all written in Swift 2.0

I have gotten the data downloaded, and I think I've been able to reference it but I'm not sure. Data/garbage does print when I convert the URL into an NSData object and print it to the console. The video files gets downloaded as a binary file however. I was able to go to the CloudKit dashboard and download the file and append '.mov' to it, and it opened in Quicktime no problem.

So I think my main issue is that I can't work out how to get the video file to actually play, since the file has no extension. I have tried appending '.mov' to the end with URLByAppendingPathExtension() to no avail. Let me know of any ideas!

Upload Video

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let tempURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
        self.uploadVideoToiCloud(tempURL)
        print("\n     Before Upload: \(tempURL)\n")
    }
}

func uploadVideoToiCloud(url: NSURL) {
    let videoRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "video", recordID: id)

    videoRecord["title"] = "This is the title"

    let videoAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: url)
    videoRecord["video"] = videoAsset

    CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase.saveRecord(videoRecord) { (record, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("upload successful")

            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Download Video

```
func downloadVideo(id: CKRecordID) {

    privateDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(id) { (results, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                    print(" Error Fetching Record  " + error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if results != nil {
                    print("pulled record")

                    let record = results!
                    let videoFile = record.objectForKey("video") as! CKAsset

                    self.videoURL = videoFile.fileURL

                    print("     After Download: \(self.videoURL!)")

                    self.videoAsset = AVAsset(URL: self.videoURL!)
                    self.playVideo()

                } else {
                    print("results Empty")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your file and rename it before uploading it

Comment: You need to generate a new file name for each video other than capturedVideo

Comment: Can u plz add full code of the function Self.playVideo() mentioned in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution ended up being that I forgot to specify the filename before I wrote the data to it. I was using URLByAppendingPathExtension and it messed up the URL, ended up using URLByAppendingPathComponent and adding a filename there. Here's the solution that worked for me! Thanks for the comments guys.

```
func downloadVideo(id: CKRecordID) {

    privateDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(id) { (results, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            if error != nil {

                    print(" Error Fetching Record  " + error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if results != nil {
                    print("pulled record")

                    let record = results as CKRecord!
                    let videoFile = record.objectForKey("video") as! CKAsset

                    self.videoURL = videoFile.fileURL as NSURL!
                    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.videoURL!)

                    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
                    let destinationPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent("filename.mov", isDirectory: false) //This is where I messed up.

                    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(destinationPath.path!, contents:videoData, attributes:nil)

                    self.videoURL = destinationPath

                    self.videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: self.videoURL!)
                    self.playVideo()

                } else {
                    print("results Empty")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The root problem is that AVPlayer expects a file extension, for example `.mov`, but `CKAsset`'s `fileURL` property points to a file that lacks an extension. The cleanest solution is to create a hard link, which avoids shuffling megabytes of data around and requires no disk space:

```
- (NSURL *)videoURL {
    return [self createHardLinkToVideoFile];
}


- (NSURL *)createHardLinkToVideoFile {
    NSError *err;
    if (![self.hardURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil]) {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] linkItemAtURL:self.asset.fileURL toURL:self.hardURL error:&err]) {
            // if creating hard link failed it is still possible to create a copy of self.asset.fileURL and return the URL of the copy
        }
    }
    return self.hardURL;
}

- (void)removeHardLinkToVideoFile {
    NSError *err;
    if ([self.hardURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil]) {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:self.hardURL error:&err]) {
        }
    }
}

- (NSURL *)hardURL {
    return [self.asset.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"];
}
```

Then in the view controller, point `AVPlayer` to `videoURL` instead of `asset.fileURL`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution for multiple video download from CloudKit. Using this you can store the video on multiple destination and get easily file path

```
import AVKit
import CloudKit

var assetForVideo = [CKAsset]()
var videoURLForGetVideo = NSURL()
database.perform(queryForVideo, inZoneWith: nil) { [weak self] record, Error in
    guard  let records = record, Error == nil else {
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        self?.assetForVideo = records.compactMap({ $0.value(forKey: "video") as? CKAsset })

        for (i,dt) in self!.assetForVideo.enumerated(){
            self!.videoURLForGetVideo = (dt.fileURL as NSURL?)!
            let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: self!.videoURLForGetVideo as URL)
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let destinationPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).appendingPathComponent(self!.assetForVideo.count == i ? "filename\(self!.assetForVideo.count).mov" : "filename\(i+1).mov", isDirectory: false)! as NSURL
            FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: destinationPath.path!, contents: videoData as Data?, attributes: nil)
            self?.videoURLForGetVideo = destinationPath
            self!.videoAssett = AVURLAsset(url: self!.videoURLForGetVideo as URL)
            let abc = self!.videoAssett.url
            let videoURL = URL(string: "\(abc)")
        }
    }
}
```